# Fastest way to generate multiple random numbers in a function in Python 2.7/Numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, random

I have a function that can use only the standard library of Python2.7 and Numpy.

The body of the function contains lots of call to random.randint() and random.random()

```
if random.random() < svRate:
    do_stuff

if random.random() < svRate:
    do_stuff

if random.random() < svRate:    
    do_stuff

if random.random() < svRate:    
    do_stuff

if random.random() < svRate:    
    do_stuff

if random.random() < svRate:
    do_stuff

if random.randint(0,5) < pRate:
    do_stuff

if random.randint(0,10) < pRate:
    do_stuff

if random.randint(10,100) < pRate:
    do_stuff
```

It's lots of boilerplate code and definitely not efficient since all that calls.
What is the best way to deal with it? The only solution I could come up with is to generate a list of random numbers in advance and pop() them when I need.
Is this the best I can do? Would it actually speed up the code?

Comment: Would depend on how you gonna use those random numbers. For example, if you are just comparing different random  numbers against the same number `svRate`, you are better off creating an array of random numbers in one go and then creating a boolean array of those comparisons and then use that array for your computations either with IF or directly. This is a general idea without considering any specifics from your actual problem.

Comment: I always need to compare them with svRate and pRate but they can change at any call of the function. A bool array would give me 50% chance of having each if statement executed and this would not be the correct behavior of the function. Right?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure as it seems there are other branching operations happening as you said - "`they can change at any call of the function`".

Comment: I meant that svRate and pRate are actually arguments of the function, they can be different at any function call.